In celery 5.4 is it possible to have a worker dynamically remove itself from a queue?
Here is the issue, I am using celery workers to load LLMs.  Each worker may have zero or one LLMs loaded.  Each worker has two queues, celery and a worker specific queue.  After a worker loads an LLM, I want it to unsubscribe from the general queue (celery).  Is this possible?  Once the worker loads an LLM, I write the worker name and the LLM it as loaded to a DB.  In addition, after the worker finishes and unloads the LLM, I would like to have the worker resubscribe to the celery queue.
I have searcher high and low, but I do not see how to have the worker modify it's queues dynamically.  I am using python 3.

I've never really seen any official support for this. From what you're describing, I suspect you can solve this by just creating two worker processes, each ready for their respective queue. If you really wanted to have one queue active and the other not active, you can try to manage this state and startup/shutdown each worker as you need. You can either use Pythons subprocesses module to handle starting/stopping, or make them into docker containers and start and stop them?

Yes, it is possible. The simplest way is probably to make your task send the "remote" command to the worker to remove itself from particular queue. There is probably a more sophisticated way to do it, but I am not a Celery expert...
